# Add a jar file to the environment variables windows 8

Tags: java, windows, cmd

So I'm trying to add a jar file to the  environment variables in windows so instead of running `java c:\mega_long_file_path\filename.jar` I can run `filename`

I tried adding `;c:\mega_long_file_path\filename.jar;` to the PATH variable in `Control Panel >System and Security > System > advance system settings > advance >  environment variables` and that didn't work , I'm positive I have done this before what am I missing?

Comment: If you want to run just `filename`, then add `c:\mega_long_file_path` to the `PATH` environment variable, and add `.JAR` to the `PATHEXT` environment variable. Then ensure that .jar files have the correct association (e.g. in cmd configure this using `assoc` and `ftype`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a batch file named `filename.bat` and put this line in it:

```
java -jar c:\mega_long_file_path\filename.jar
```

Then put this batch file into your PATH or update your PATH to point to the directory where you created it.

After that you should be able to run `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly I think what you want is to add it to CLASSPATH instead of PATH (Create the CLASSPATH environment variable if it is not already there)